# Countif in another sheet multiple Columns

Tags: vba, excel

I want my sub to Count if a cell in either column H or R in the sheet is "1". After "9000 google searches", I hope you can help me on how to do it correctly?

```
Dim studyboard1 As Long
studyboard1 = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Sheets("Delayed Students").Range("H:H, R:R"), 1)
```

I also tried

```
studyboard121 = WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Worksheets("Delayed Students").Columns("H,R"), "121")
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to count each separately then subtract when they are both:

```
Dim HCount As Long
HCount = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Sheets("Delayed Students").Range("H:H"), 1)

Dim RCount As Long
RCount = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Sheets("Delayed Students").Range("R:R"), 1)

Dim BothCount As Long
'If you want to remove the duplicate count when R and H are 1 then uncomment the following line
'BothCount = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIfs(Sheets("Delayed Students").Range("R:R"), 1, Sheets("Delayed Students").Range("H:H"), 1)

Dim studyboard1 As Long
studyboard1 = HCount + RCount - BothCount
```

Comment: What - Why do you make a "Bothcount" and subtract? Cant you just make the 2 counts and the add them together?

Comment: @Simon that depend on your data, if you have 1 in H and 1 in R it will count that row twice, if this is what you want then yes remove the Both count.  If you want it only counted once then leave it in as it will remove 1 from the count of 2 when the row has both 1 in R and 1 in H.

Comment: Row R and row H contains the 'same kind of data', where it for some reason just got moved over to another row - So i need to count both sadly.. But thank you for the good explanation! :)

Comment: Then just remove the BothCount references and you will get your answer.